# What are the ways to connect to an ec2 instance in a private subnet?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, ssh-tunnel, amazon-vpc

I have a VPC with private and public subnets and I want to ssh into one of the machines which is in the private subnets.

I have heard of the bastion method but want to try others too, please help me with any methods you know,

I also have the NAT Gateway.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Your question appears to be broad and the StackExchange Q&A sites are intended for providing specific answers to specific problems. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask) and consider revising your question, deleting your question or asking more than one question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because This is well-covered in documentation and countless blog posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you're using a VPN (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpn-connections.html) or Direct Connect (https://aws.amazon.com/directconnect/) setup to an existing network, a bastion host on a public IP is pretty much your only option.

You can also connect from a host in another VPC if you've setup VPC Peering (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-peering.html).